# Ghostscript pdf to jpg windows/linux color differences

Tags: php, linux, pdf, ghostscript

I'm coding a function using ghostscript to convert a multipages PDF into one JPG per page.

Everything works fine on windows with ghostcript 9.05 and WAMP Server.

The problem is that I have differences between WAMP and my linux server (1&1 Hosting) :

The command is working : i can convert pdf to jpg, but problem :
 colors are totally over-saturated.

I tried the option -dUseCIEColor : colors are now fine, except for dark background who are now gray / lighter.

Why these differences ? I used same version on windows and linux.

I heard about ICC color profiles, but i don't know if its the good way because i use default.

If someone have informations... Thanks

Or, if you know a good alternative to ghostscript to convert PDF into JPG...

Here is the command I'm using :

`$ghostscriptCommand="gs -dUseCIEColor -dSAFER -dBATCH -dNOPAUSE -dPDFSETTINGS=/screen -sDEVICE=jpeg -dJPEGQ=60 -dTextAlphaBits=4 -dGraphicsAlphaBits=4 -r144 -sOutputFile=$dir/p%03d.jpg $pdfFile";
    exec($ghostscriptCommand);`

Comment: Maybe a code? Maybe you should watch your language, I think you misunderstood what is all about here.

Comment: I'm sorry if my english is bad, i do my best to be understandable...
The code i'm using is really simple, i don't know if if will help. (i'll post it in 1 min)

Comment: Color is perceptual. You assume the .pdf is correct, because it is the one you are starting with, but that may just be an illusion. Is the .pdf a cmyk? the jpg is rgb? Print them both out and neither will match the screen. Print either out on 2 different printers and they won't match either. "color matching" is an attempt to make images match, but it is complex. http://tinyurl.com/a6lvnu2 Does it really matter? Does the document have just a few colors or lots of colors?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Having dicussed this on the Ghostscript IRC channel, the problem is that the Linux server is running Ghostscript 8.71, rather than 9.05 - the 9.xx versions introduced an entirely new color workflow, based on ICC profiles.

The only realistic solution is to update the Linux server to 9.05.